# logging out of a restful service is just destroying the token locally?

Tags: rest, api, jwt, access-token

On a restful API. If I want to log out, say I am using a Single Page App, connected to a restful service. All I have to do (assuming the token doesn't expire) is destroy the token locally. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally, jwt will not be saved on the server. destroying the token locally means destroying the login information.